# How does synchronized yield better performance compared to volatile in my code

Tags: java, synchronized, volatile

OK, so I have this code:

```
public class RaceCondition { 

  private static boolean done;

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException{ 
    new Thread(new Runnable() { 
      public void run() {
        int i = 0; 
        while(!done) { i++; }
        System.out.println("Done!"); }
      } 
    ).start();

    System.out.println("OS: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    done = true;
    System.out.println("flag done set to true");
  } 
}
```

on Mac, it doesn't work...what I mean is that: "flag done set to true" doesn't print, meaning that the thread didn't see the change to the flag.

So I could fix this my makingthe flag volatile:

```
public static volatile boolean done;
```

Even though it works now when I run it, the thing is, each read and write access will bypass cache and go all the way memory, so going all the way to the memory barrier surely would result in poor performance?

so I could write it this way instead:

```
 public class RaceCondition {
  private static boolean done;

  public static synchronized boolean getFlag() {
    return done;
  }

  public static synchronized void setFlag(boolean flag) {
    done = flag;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while(!getFlag()) {
          i++;
        }
        System .out.println("Done!");
      }
    }
    ).start();

    System.out.println("OS: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    setFlag(true);
    System.out.println("flag done set to true");
  }
}
```

But I don't see how the performance is could be better than the previous example? Because synchronized makes you enter the memory barrier as well for read and write access by default?

The only real advantage I see here is that there is better coordinated access to the flag as opposed to using volatile...

So is there performance gain in particular?

Comment: The JIT probably performs optimistic lock elision in the second case which it cannot do in the first; try and see what `-XX:+PrintCompilation` yields

Comment: Wouldn't the monitor lock contention especially under high concurrency surpass the uncached lookup by and large?

Comment: Try again with 4 concurrent threads

Comment: Only in very rare circumstances should you be worried about performance problems like this. And if you would have requirements that require best performance, you would probably be choosing C/C++ (or equivalents, or domain specific languages).

Comment: Apart from that, a memory barrier also involves going all the way to memory and bypassing the cache (or rather updating the cache to ensure data is up to date). Also: explain to us how what benchmarks you took to get to your conclusion.